# Laravel 7.0-session got empty after redirection

Tags: php, laravel, session

Trying to login using SSO which in which i need to redirect it to its own login panel

Middleware

```
        if(empty(Session::get('token')))
        {
            $code = $request->query('code');
            if (!isset($code))
            {
                (new LoginController)->login($request);
            }
            elseif (empty($request->query('state')) || ($request->query('state') !== Session::get('session_state')))
            {
                Session::forget('token');
                Session::forget('session_state');
                (new LoginController)->login($request);
            }
            else
            {

                (new LoginController)->getToken($code);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            (new LoginController)->checkTokenExpire();
        }
```

Controller

```
    public function login()
    {
        Session::forget('token');
        $state = $this->getState();
        session()->put('session_state',$state);
        session()->save();
        $authorizationUrl = $this->getUrl($state);
        redirect()->to($authorizationUrl)->send();
    }
```

Routes

```
Route::get('/', 'AbcController@index')->middleware('loginAuth');
```

if i try to print session `dd(session()->all())` before the redirection it return the `session_state` but after redirection when login successfull and flow came back to my server session got empty

Comment: try same_site=>null in config/session.php

Comment: tried..still the same